# How to use scanf() correctly when reading input into an array using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

For some reason, reading input using `scanf()` won't work this way:

```
int main() {
    int arr1_size = 0;

    // Reading array size
    scanf("%d", &arr1_size);

    int* arr1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * arr1_size);

    // Reading and printing array values
    for(int i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", arr1);
        arr1++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++) {
        printf("%d", arr1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You're losing the starting address of `arr1` here: `scanf("%d", arr1); arr1++;`.  I think more correctly, `scanf` is working as expected, `printf` is not.

Comment: Use `scanf("%d", arr1 + i);` to preserve the pointer from `malloc`. Then `printf` will work correctly.

Comment: Before issuing `malloc` it would be better to go on only `if(arr1_size > 0)`

Comment: Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly improved version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    int arr1_size = 0;

    printf("Hello,\nPlease enter the size of the first array:");
    scanf("%d", &arr1_size);

    int *arr1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * arr1_size);

    printf("\nPlease enter arr1 of size %d:\n", arr1_size);
    for(int i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", arr1 + i);
    }
    printf("\nArray contents:\n");    
    for(int i = 0; i < arr1_size; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", arr1[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
./scan
Hello,
Please enter the size of the first array:3

Please enter arr1 of size 3:
1
2
3

Array contents:
1 
2 
3
```

Comment: Thanks!
Could you please explain what exactly went wrong?  
I understand that after my scan arr1 didn't point to the initial address anymore but doesn't printing with indices fix this?  
Did the scan I used work at all?

Comment: As already said, when entering data for an array with `scanf` you need to use the adress of the "ith" array element (`arr1 + i`) when entering the "ith" data item. In addition I have modified printf so that each array item is printed on its own line: it's easier to see what is printed (for a small array of course).